# Multithreading and the entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I've built a website with ASP.NET MVC3, using Entity Framework 4. It is supposed to be a questionnarie.

All of my controllers use the same DbContext Class like this:

```
private aim_spg_dk_dbEntities db = new aim_spg_dk_dbEntities();
```

I was wondering, if this would mess things up, with a multi user site. If 100 users are answering the questionnarie, what would happen? Should i use threading, and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private aim_spg_dk_dbEntities db = new aim_spg_dk_dbEntities();
```

This is fine - you are creating a new DB context instance for each request - so each user will be using a separate DB context instance. What you cannot do is share the same DB context instance across multiple threads (DB contexts are not thread safe).

Answer (score 1):

The entity context is going to be thread specific and execute statements as transactions. Unless you are using shared data between request threads, there's nothing to worry about.